# ValueError: shapes (3,2) and (3,) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix A

```
A= np.array([[1,2,3],[2,1,1]])
```

I want to calculate vector `v` based on [image]

I have calculated the inverse of A by using `linalg.pinv`

```
inverse= np.linalg.pinv(A)
```

How can I calculate `v`?
I have tried using `np.dot(inverse, np.array([1,1,1])`, but it returns the `ValueError: shapes (3,2) and (3,) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong shape for `(1 1 1)`: it is a column vector, not a row one.

Try this:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,1,1]])
one_array = np.ones((3, 1))
A_inv = np.linalg.pinv(A)

v = np.dot(A_inv, np.dot(A, one_array))
```

If you print the shape of `one_array`, it is:

```py
print(one_array.shape)

(3, 1)
```

while if you define it as `np.array([1, 1, 1])` the shape is `(3,)`, i.e. a row vector.

`v` will be:

```sh
[[1.02857143]
 [0.85714286]
 [1.08571429]]
```